# Why is the monero GUI synchronization starting from zero every time the daemon boots up?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

http://prntscr.com/hpeep2

As you can see, even though I have a 34 GB file, it is telling me that I have over 1M blocks left to synchronize. But earlier today it was telling me there are about 20K left. What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The current GUI looks like its synchronizing twice. This may be what you are seeing.

Basically, your client first needs to synchronize with the network. This is the downloading and verification of the blockchain.

Then, your client needs to scan the blockchain with your private keys. This is probably what you are seeing.

Comment: The thing is that I haven't downloaded the whole blockchain yet.

Comment: The blockchain is currently 37 GB (at least on a linux system). Sometimes when the blockchain gets thick (there were a lot of transactions at a certain blockheight, for instance) verification time can slow down so it seems to stall.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this. Because the daemon wouldn't start from the GUI, I started it manually. This downloaded it to the default location (a different drive)...